# Get rows having same column value

Tags: mysql

I have a following table where I need to find the maximum consumers of a company.
I have a **users** table and a **company** table.A users can use many products of a different companies and a company can have many users as its consumers.
**user_id is a foreign key used in this table from users table and company_id is a foreign_key used from company table**

TABLE **consumers_company**

Suppose we have the following data:-

```
 user_id | company_id 
---------------------
   6     |    1      
   6     |    2      
   7     |    5       
   8     |    8      
   8     |    1
   8     |    8
```

Now as we can see company 1 has maximum users.I am using this query to find those companies which have users more than 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM consumers_company
WHERE company_id IN (
SELECT company_id
FROM consumers_company
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(company_id) > 1)
```

My Output:-

```
user_id | company_id
--------------------
 6      |  1
 8      |  8        
 8      |  1         
 8      |  8
```

Required Output:-

```
user_id | company_id
--------------------
 6      |  1
 8      |  1
```

I am a beginner in MySQL.Please help me out.

Comment: how do you logically get to your required output in plain speak?

Comment: You have no primary key. This may prove problematic.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from consumers_company where company_id in 
(select company_id from consumers_company group by company_id
order by count(distinct user_id) desc limit 1)
```

First find out the company which have the most unique user_id relation in the `consumers_company` table.And the give out all its consumers.

Comment: I already found that but having problem now to further find out the company which has maximum consumers.

Comment: Just use the sub query, it is the company id which have maximum consumers count